# Embedding a YouTube Video Based on a PHP Variable

Tags: php, mysql, html, youtube, embed

I have a website that I am creating for a class project. The website shows information about bands (which is stored in a mysql database). I am trying to spruce up the site a bit, and I would like to embed a YouTube video based on the band's name. Say, for instance, I have "Led Zeppelin" stored in my database. How can I take a PHP variable containing "Led Zeppelin", search YouTube using that variable, find a random video, and then embed that in the website? From the research I've done, it seems you can only embed YouTube videos if you know the exact address of the video.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See [Youtube API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the youtube PHP API
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html#Searching_for_Videos

Answer (score 0):

You can use a script that match you search query or tags from youtube API like http://www.scriptsmashup.com/include_mytube_demo.php