# JSP/HTML:Embeding a youtube video link from a mySQL database

Tags: jsp, video, youtube

(Hint:I've just started using JSP with little to no previous reference, so unfortunately I'm mixing HTML code with JSP segments, so I'd appreciate some understanding until I get a good grip of the subject)

I've been searching for about an evening across this and other almost obsolete sites for my problem (although [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103269/display-youtube-video-using-link-from-database), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525168/embedding-a-youtube-video-based-on-a-php-variable) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866847/id-like-to-select-a-random-youtube-video-from-mysql-database-and-display-it-on) people scratch the surface of it.

I have a table on my mySQL database called "video" where youtube links are to be stored by their uploaders from table "student".

I wanted to embed each video its uploader has put in the database at a jsp page, so I thought that it could be something easy like embeding pictures.

Random youtube embed code:

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tvTRZJ-4EyI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This is where I got so far (snippet of my code):

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>

<%  
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    int am=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("armht"));

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/final","xxxx", "xxxx");  

            Statement st = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet studentvideos;
                    studentvideos=st.executeQuery("select video.videolink "
                                + "from video, student "
                                + "where video.studno=student.studno "
                                + "and student.studno='" +am+ "' "
                                );                       
%> 

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Random JSP page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
<%  
            out.println("<b>Videos: </b><p>");

            while (studentvideos.next()) 
            {  
            %>
                <iframe width="640" height="360" src="+studentvideos.getString(1)+" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
            <%
            }
            out.println("<br>" + "<br>");
%>    
        </center>
    </body>
</html>

<%
            st.close();
        con.close();  
%>
```

The result is:

[image]

And the problem, of course is the "`<iframe width="640" height="360" src="+studentvideos.getString(1)+" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>";`" line, where it seems that I may:

i)have done a moronic syntax error, or

ii)tried something that is not possible without completely changing my poor-but-kinda-simplistic code.

[Here](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#youtube-videos) lies a workaround, where instead of a video player, only an image which directs to the link with the video, and I might end up using this method.

But still, I want to know how (and if) it is possible to embed a video link from a database to a jsp page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the code to embed a youtube video to a page is this:

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9Ht7ILp_DLY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

BUT, the link of a youtube video is:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Ht7ILp_DLY
```

There is a difference between the link above and the link inside the embed code:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/9Ht7ILp_DLY
```

All I had to do was to have a trigger where it would turn a youtube link to a embed-friendly link:

```
create trigger embedthevideo
before insert on video
for each row
SET NEW.videolink = REPLACE(NEW.videolink, "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/");
```

And with the precious help of [Ketan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1230360/ketan) at the jsp page:

```
<%  
        out.println("<b>Videos: </b><p>");

        while (studentvideos.next()) 
        {  
        %>
           <iframe width="640" height="360" src="<%=studentvideos.getString(1)%>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <%
        }
        out.println("<br>" + "<br>");
%>
```

It works like a charm:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your all other code is correct than, as you expect only below lines needs to be updated.

```
<%  
        out.println("<b>Videos: </b><p>");

        while (studentvideos.next()) 
        {  
        %>
            <iframe width="640" height="360" src="<%=studentvideos.getString(1)%>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <%
        }
        out.println("<br>" + "<br>");
%>
```

Comment: I tried your code and now it prints "";" at the end of where the embedded video player should be [link](http://i67.tinypic.com/28gxe7q.png)

Comment: Opps sorry. See the  updated code above. **";**. This should not be there at the end. But the issue is **<%=studentvideos.getString(1)%>** is not returning any value.

Comment: Try to see view source of page or log it. You will have better idea.

Answer (score 0):

**JSP/HTML:Embeding a youtube video link without mySQL database**

Another solution for generating embed youtube code

*Steps* :

1. Copy youtube video url.
2. Paste url [here](https://youtubeembedcode.com/en/)

Now you have *Youtube embed code* paste this code where you want to show it on screen. 
Thanks :)

Comment: This doesn't really "fix" the issue here, since in my system the user has to paste an ordinary youtube url from his browser of app, and then my system needs to embed the video to a page. This is just for plain modifications of an embed that a developer might use to customise an embedded youtube video, and there's already this kinda function within the youtube itself.

Comment: Yess , I tried to do this ... But it doesn't works in my system so I found this one solution  :)